# Error during socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverip= "192.168.43.237"
serverport= 2221
s.connect((serverip, serverport))
```

> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: stop firewall at server program

Comment: did you setup a server to receive this connection?

Comment: Ya , it was actually due to the firewall running at server machine